# Как настроить Angularjs google api localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api

Подключаю так

```
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
```

В контроллере пишу так

```
 var locations = [
            ['loan 1', 55.787004, 37.102659,  'address 1']

        ];

        function initialize() {

            var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.890542, 151.274856),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                myOptions);

            setMarkers(map, locations)

        }


        function setMarkers(map, locations) {

            var marker, i

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                var loan = locations[i][0]
                var lat = locations[i][1]
                var long = locations[i][2]
                var add = locations[i][3]

                latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, title: loan, position: latlngset
                });
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())


                var content = "Loan Number: " + loan + '</h3>' + "Address: " + add

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, content, infowindow) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    };
                })(marker, content, infowindow));

            }
        }
        initialize();
```

Получаю такую картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибок нет, добавил такую штуку

```
  $timeout(function () {
            initialize();
        }.bind(this), 5000);
```

И карта загрузилась. 
Наверное нужно уточнить что карта находится на 2-й скрытой вкладке, даже с таймером при ожидании больше 5 секунд и переходе на вкладку получаю такую же не загруженную карту. В общем поставил инициализацию карты в функцию открытия вкладки и работает =)

Вот если бы кто то ещё подсказал как по кнопке обновлять карту

Comment: какие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: что за вторая скрытая вкладка?

Comment: табы обычные, на 1-м контент табе нету карты, на второй вкладке есть

Comment: что-то мне кажется лучше использовать готовый ангуляровский компонент: https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/